# autocomplete: failed to load response data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I built an autocomplete, and on my machine it works perfectly. But now I put it life, and it does not work. When you type text the waiting-image starts spinning but nothing happens. Fortunately the page is ok, so the user can proceed, but the autocomplete-suggestions do not appear.

This is all new to me, but I started to examine the Inspect in Google Chrome and I noticed the response message 'failed to load response data'. But now I don't understand what to do with this problem. How can I solve this? The same happens in Edge.

You can reproduce the error like this:

1. go to www.gratisverlanglijstje.nl
2. login like **testac** password **testac**
3. click inside the menu the upper button '**Verlanglijstje van testac**'
4. click the second green button '**Cadeau toevoegen (vrije invoer)**'
5. type in the first text box **lego**

now the autocomplete list should appear but nothing happens, and inside the text box on the right side the wait image starts (and keeps) spinning...
I think you will get the most information from the google inspect window, but if you need code snippets, just tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Hoi buurman!

Have you tried debugging your sever-side code?
The ajax object is returning your default error page

```
<h2>Er is helaas een fout opgetreden</h2>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg" style="color:Red;">Klik op de Menu-knop rechtsboven voor jouw mogelijkheden. Ga anders terug naar de homepage en log daar (opnieuw) in. Dan moet het goed gaan.</span><br /><br />
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSol"></span><br /><br />
<a href='/default.aspx'>homepage</a><br /><br /><br />
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1">Mocht je er niet uitkomen, stuur dan gerust een bericht met het <a href='/contact.aspx'>contactformulier</a>. Vermeld foutcode E1 in het bericht, en beschrijf wat je deed voordat de foutmelding zich voordeed.</span><br /><br />
```

Try wrapping the body of the `GetSuggesties` method in a try catch and see if an exception is thrown somewhere down the line.

Let me know if there's something I'm missing on my end.

**EDIT**
I found out by simple changing your ajax a little bit:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'cadeausuggestiesservice.asmx/GetSuggesties',
                method: 'post',
                data: { term: request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

Now you can browse the object in the console

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I changed the error to console.log but the object doesn't give (me) much information. If you change the url from cadeau_toevoegen.aspx to cadeau_toevoegen**test**.aspx you can look at the console
Please look at https://www.gratisverlanglijstje.nl/beheerder/cadeausuggestiesservice.asmx

Comment: No problem, unfortunately I can't get any more information either. The error must be server-side and your `GetSuggesties` method doesn't return an error. How about you catch the exception server-side and send it back as a result of your `GetSuggesties` method. There's isn't anymore information available in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try GetSuggesties to return more error information, as you suggested...

Comment: Try looking into `Environment.InteractiveMode` for server-side. You could create an error page that displays the stacktrace or more information about the error. The ajax request is handled correctly and returns without an error. It's the server that decides to create the error page as a return value due to an error

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the knowledge to do so. I posted my asmx-code inside the original post.

Comment: There's not much I can test using your code. Are you sure no exception is thrown? If you set a breakpoint, does it get hit? Is there an exception in the console on the server-side?

Comment: Thanks for your help DerpyNerd. As you can see I already found out the answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my web.config solved my problem:

```
<webServices>
<protocols>
<add name="HttpGet"/>
<add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yx7be39(v=vs.100).aspx and http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2006/12/22/How-to-enable-an-ASPNET-WebService-to-listen-to-HTTP/